# Convert pytorch tensor to opencv mat and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, pytorch

I want to convert pytorch tensors to opencv mat and vice versa in C++. I have these two functions:

```
cv::Mat TensorToCVMat(torch::Tensor tensor)
{
    std::cout << "converting tensor to cvmat\n";
    tensor = tensor.squeeze().detach().permute({1, 2, 0});
    tensor = tensor.mul(255).clamp(0, 255).to(torch::kU8);
    tensor = tensor.to(torch::kCPU);
    int64_t height = tensor.size(0);
    int64_t width = tensor.size(1);
    cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC3);
    std::memcpy((void *)mat.data, tensor.data_ptr(), sizeof(torch::kU8) * tensor.numel());
    return mat.clone();
}

torch::Tensor CVMatToTensor(cv::Mat mat)
{
    std::cout << "converting cvmat to tensor\n";
    cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    cv::Mat matFloat;
    mat.convertTo(matFloat, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255);
    auto size = matFloat.size();
    auto nChannels = matFloat.channels();
    auto tensor = torch::from_blob(matFloat.data, {1, size.height, size.width, nChannels});
    return tensor.permute({0, 3, 1, 2});
}
```

In my code I load two images (`image1` and `image2`) and I want to convert them to pytorch tensors and then back to opencv mat to check if it works. The problem is that I get an memory access error on the first call of `TensorToCVMat` and I cant figure out whats wrong as I do not have much experience with C++ programming.

```
cv::Mat image1;
image1 = cv::imread(argv[1]);
if (!image1.data)
{
    std::cout << "no image data\n";
    return -1;
}
cv::Mat image2;
image2 = cv::imread(argv[2]);
if (!image2.data)
{
    std::cout << "no image data\n";
    return -1;
}

torch::Tensor tensor1 = CVMatToTensor(image1);
cv::Mat new_image1 = TensorToCVMat(tensor1); // <<< this is where the memory access error is thrown
torch::Tensor tensor2 = CVMatToTensor(image2);
cv::Mat new_image2 = TensorToCVMat(tensor2);
```

It would be great if you could give me hints or an explanation to solve this problem.

Comment: `torch::from_blob` doesn't take ownership of the data buffer, and as far as I can tell, `permute` doesn't make a deep copy. `matFloat` goes out of scope at the end of `CVMatToTensor`, and deallocates the buffer that the returned `Tensor` wraps. | On the other hand, the `mat.clone()` at the end of `TensorToCVMat` is redundant, since `mat` already owns the buffer you copied the data into in the preceding statement. One more copy is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if the error is happening at the memcpy step. But you can use the `void* data` variant of the [Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) constructor

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

and you can skip the memcpy step

```
tensor = uint8_tensor //shape: (h, w, 3)
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr());
return mat;
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using torch>=1.7.0.

For a tensor of **dtype=uint8** and size **[1, 3, height, width]**
this is what worked for me

```
cv::Mat torchTensortoCVMat(torch::Tensor& tensor)
    {
        tensor = tensor.squeeze().detach();
        tensor = tensor.permute({1, 2, 0}).contiguous();
        tensor = tensor.mul(255).clamp(0, 255).to(torch::kU8);
        tensor = tensor.to(torch::kCPU);
        int64_t height = tensor.size(0);
        int64_t width = tensor.size(1);
        cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr<uchar>());
        return mat.clone();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

My tensor shape was `500x500x3`, I have to add `tensor.reshape({width * height * 3})` to get the actual image

```
cv::Mat TensorToCVMat(torch::Tensor tensor)
{
    // torch.squeeze(input, dim=None, *, out=None) → Tensor
    // Returns a tensor with all the dimensions of input of size 1 removed.
    // tensor.detach
    // Returns a new Tensor, detached from the current graph.
    // permute dimension, 3x700x700 => 700x700x3
    tensor = tensor.detach().permute({1, 2, 0});
    // float to 255 range
    tensor = tensor.mul(255).clamp(0, 255).to(torch::kU8);
    // GPU to CPU?, may not needed
    tensor = tensor.to(torch::kCPU);
    // shape of tensor
    int64_t height = tensor.size(0);
    int64_t width = tensor.size(1);

    // Mat takes data form like {0,0,255,0,0,255,...} ({B,G,R,B,G,R,...})
    // so we must reshape tensor, otherwise we get a 3x3 grid
    tensor = tensor.reshape({width * height * 3});
    // CV_8UC3 is an 8-bit unsigned integer matrix/image with 3 channels
    cv::Mat imgbin(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr());

    return imgbin;
}
```