# LibTorch C++: Converting Tensor back to Image, Result is 3x3 Grid?

Tags: c++, matrix, tensor, libtorch

I am working on some code that takes a matrix object (assume this behaves as cv::Mat), converts to tensor, does a forward pass through my model, and converts back to my matrix object. However I have one issue persisting. That is, my resulting matrix is a 3x3 grid of the result. I tested my conversion codes (Matrix to Tensor and back) by just passing the image through both, and the resulting image is correct. This leads me to believe it is something with how the forward pass creates your output tensor? How should I work with the output tensor to fix the problem?

Code for context

Matrix to Tensor:

```
int numel = rows * cols * depth;
assert(numel > 0);

tensor_image = torch::zeros({ rows, cols, depth }, torch::kFloat);

std::memcpy(tensor_image.data_ptr<float>(), Image.GetConstDataPtr(), sizeof(float) * numel);

tensor_image = tensor_image.permute({ 2, 0, 1 }).unsqueeze(0);
```

Forward Pass:

```
at::Tensor output = torch::zeros({ tensor_image.sizes()[0], tensor_image.sizes()[1], tensor_image.sizes()[2], tensor_image.sizes()[3] }, torch::kFloat);

device = torch::kCUDA;

// Move model to GPU
module.to(device);

// Move target to gpu 
tensor_image = tensor_image.to(device);
// Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
at::Tensor output = module.forward({ tensor_image }).toTensor();

output = output.to(torch::kCPU);
```

Tensor to Matrix:

```
int numel = height * width * depth;
assert(numel > 0);

Image.Resize(height, width, depth);

at::Tensor tensor_image_cpy = tensor_image.squeeze(0).permute({ 1, 2, 0 });

std::memcpy(Image.GetDataPtr(), tensor_image_cpy.data_ptr<float>(), sizeof(float) * numel);
```

Comment: What is the model supposed to do ? What is its expected output shape ? Can you show its implementation ?

Comment: The expected output shape is [1, 3, 1024, 1024], so an RGB image. The model used is an example from this repo: 

https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix

Comment: For what it is worth, this model worked when converted to .ONNX and ran using OpenCV's DNN Module.

Comment: Okay then, can you clarify what " my resulting matrix is a 3x3 grid of the result" means ? I'm not sure I understand. Also, can you print the shape of `output` ? And I imagine you convert your `output` tensor into a cv::Mat with the same code as in your 3rd snippet, but with replacing `tensor_image` by `output`, right ?

Comment: Sure thing. So the output shape is [1, 3, 1024, 1024]. By 3x3 grid, I mean that the image is "shrunk" and placed in a 3x3 grid pattern where each piece of the grid is the image (like a tictacto board, each square being the image). Hopefully that description helps. 

You are correct, output is converted to matrix, and it is a tensor output from model.forward().toTensor()

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem, and posted below. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. Citing yugo's answer to this question:

[Convert pytorch tensor to opencv mat and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512310/convert-pytorch-tensor-to-opencv-mat-and-vice-versa-in-c)

You need to make sure to reshape the data:

```
tensor_image_cpy = tensor_image.reshape({ width * height * depth });
```

Hope this helps others who run into this issue.

Comment: Glad you found the solution ! please accept your answer in order to close the thread :)